# How to use "gsUtil" to get financial reports of apps?

Tags: java, android, python, financial, gsutil

### Background

When you publish an app, you can access the financial report via [**this website**](https://wallet.google.com/merchant) that can lead you to [**this website**](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2/#ReportsPlace) which leads to  :

> https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=SOME_NUMBERS#ReportsPlace

where "SOME_NUMBERS" is probably a unique ID for your account or something.

at the bottom, it says :

> Financial reports are also available for programmatic access through
> Google Cloud Storage and the gsutil tool. Your reports are stored in
> this private bucket:
>
> gs://pubsite_prod_rev_SOME_NUMBERS

(same note about SOME_NUMBERS as before)

### The problem

After installing both Python requirements (from [**here**](http://www.python.org/download)) and the gsutil (from [**here**](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)) , I can't find out how to really use what they've written.

Not only that, but for any command I try to run there, I get:

```
SyntaxError: encoding problem: utf8
```

I've found some posts here on stackOverflow talking about this error, but since I don't know python, I find it hard to understand how to fix it.

### The question

How do you really use the gsUtil?

Is it possible to fix this issue?

Is it possible to access the financial data in any other way? Is there maybe a Java alternative? Maybe even an SDK that has all of the available commands?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing too. what I found so far is you configure it first. via "gsutil configure" I'll post an answer here later when I found the solution